# Windows text editor with dynamic inline spell check

Tags: editor, text-editor, spell-checking

Can someone suggest a text editor with dynamic inline spell check for PHP / HTML programming? I am looking for a windows editor similar to Textmate on Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TextPad (http://www.textpad.com) - you can install syntax definitions ([http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/syna2g.htm](http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/syna2g.html)l) to handle PHP, HTML, etc. and it supports spell checking.